# PHP how to redirect url to email address and initiate user's mail client

Tags: php, email, redirect

I am writing a URL redirector service in php. Is there a way to use header('location:.....') or other means to redirect from a url to an email address and initiate user's default mail client, in the same way as clicking a mailto:..... link works?

For example, if user enters link http://redirector-service-url.com/xyz123 in the browser, their default mail client would launch with a specified email address associated with this shortcut, in the same way it would launch if they clicked a 
    link?

Would it have to do with the headers returned by the script?  I'm sure this could be done with javascript, but I was hoping for a pure php solution...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `header('Location: mailto:...');`? You can't control how the browser handles that protocol, either. Just depends on how *that browser* handles it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
header("Location: mailto:someone@domain.com");
```

Comment: So now i just feel stupid. Lol this is exactly right.  I had typed 'mailto:test@test.com' into the browser address bar and gotten an error, so i had assumed using 'header(location....' would not work.  Thats what i get for assuming.  Thanks for the tip, works perfectly.

Comment: I had assumed the browser would handle it! Doh. Thanks Edward.